# Mocking a TraceListener with Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, trace, system.diagnostics

Why does the Moq Verify fail with a "Moq.MockException : Invocation was not performed on the mock"?

```
var mock = new Mock<TraceListener>();
var ts = new TraceSource("traceSourceName", SourceLevels.Verbose);
ts.Listeners.Add(mock.Object);

var message = "the message";

ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, message);
ts.Flush();
mock.Verify(x => x.WriteLine(message));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question has been on here a long time however the answer is as follows...

When you write a trace event through TraceSource it calls your trace listeners TraceEvent method to do the tracing - so you need to verify calls to listener.TraceEvent, not listener.WriteLine...

```
var mock = new Mock<TraceListener>();
var ts = new TraceSource("traceSourceName", SourceLevels.Verbose);
ts.Listeners.Add(mock.Object);

var message = "the message";

ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, message);

mock.Verify(x => x.TraceEvent(It.IsAny<TraceEventCache>(), "traceSourceName", 
    TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, message), Times.Once(), "Expected a trace");
```

Hope this helps someone!

Cheers,

Morgan

Comment: +1 - Nice answer! Unrelated to your answer, [your quantization code](http://sariendotnet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r20/trunk/convert/AgiConvert/AgiConvert/src/Quantizer.cs) is quite popular and included in a lot of other libraries under many licenses. Is there a place I can find your original Quantizer & OctreeQuantizer classes so I can add the appropriate references & recognition. Thanks!

Comment: Brandon - thanks! The original article is on MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx. This includes a link to the source code. Feel free to link back to this article, I no longer work for Microsoft but a link back to the original is better than nothing!

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the reference and the code. It's certainly saved me a tun of time.

Answer (score 0):

The test states that the `WriteLine` method must be called, but it is not. Looking at the code this is most likely because this test has exposed a bug in your `TraceSource.TraceEvent` or `TraceSource.Flush` method. Double-check those methods and you should be good to go!

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179757/moq-invocation-was-not-perfomed-on-the-mock-can-you-help-explain).

Comment: If I use a fake, the WriteLine method is called.

Comment: a fake what? What do you mean with fake? Post the two metods mentioned in my answer, and perhaps we can see something from that.