# Apply TDD to a new project that uses a framework/language that the developers are not familiar with?

Tags: tdd

I've heard that if you are a complete beginner at a new technology, is highly not recommended to  use TDD.
Is that true? I've seeing graduates having good results on teams that apply TDD, although they were surrounded by people with some good years on their backs developing.

Which are your 2 cents on the topic?

Comment: I think its the opposite.. if you're unfamiliar with a language or framework then you should definitely use TDD as it will help make sure your logic and use of the language/framework is correct..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1271716/126014

Comment: Mark Seeman I disagree, no offence here, but unit test is not always TDD. And the question is not about prototyping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always rely on TDD, no matter what technology used.

Not using TDD means energy waste, never ending task, regression, unsatifaction, etc.

Maybe what is called TDD means clarification : write a red test first, and then write minimalistic code so that test becomes green. No matter if it is pure unit testing (ie test of a function), higher-level integration testing, functional testing or... manual testing. After all TDD terminology doesn't event specify if the test is automated or not.

So if you're completely new to a technology, may be automated unit-test with TDD is a bit overkill. But do TDD anyway. Use older tool you know, use higher level of testing, even on Excel spreadsheet with manual checking.

In short : yes, use TDD.