# Creating a Skill Calculator for Runescape

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am beginning C++. I have a long way to go and I am one to never stop learning. I want to create a project for myself that will allow me to learn as I go. It will also give me the motivation and possibly add to my portfolio when I graduate.

The runescape skill calculator will ask for your current experience in the current skill of your choosing and your desired level.

For Example: my woodcutting experience is 60 and I want to get to lvl 5 which is 120 exp. That means im 60 experience away. by cutting oak logs I get 5 experience per log. The calculator would tell me I need to cut 12 Oak logs. All these numbers are made up.

So to my question. Where would I even begin? Hoping it would have buttons to press.

Sorry pretty new to all this. I will start with getting what I want in a Command Line first. I will be using Visual C++ 2010 express. Not sure of all the tools I will need as I am new. I can not go into detail as I do not know how I am going about this. Vague was good. Thank you

Comment: Learn basic c++. Stick to command line programs in the beginning. Once you gain experience with that then maybe move up to creating guis.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you stop and think this through first. You've provided no information about which tools or platforms you have access to. Your question is very vague. If you want help, my suggestion is to focus your question much more than you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a general question can only get a general answer:

- First, build the program to run interactively from the command line with correct behaviour.
- Then, (if you haven't designed it this way) extract the code into a class.  This will allow you to call it from future programs.
- Then, write an GUI that interfaces with the class.
- A good set of [unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540960/how-to-write-good-unit-tests) will help throughout this project, and will make you more marketable when you present your portfolio.

For more specific answers, ask again with more detail provided.

Comment: classes and unit tests are good software engineering practices, but I would recommend against them for an absolute beginner.  Learn your way around the syntax of functions and expressions, have fun writing some code.  Then learn about good software engineering when you are fluent in the language.

Comment: I agree with @luqui's comment for an absolute beginner.  I saw that the OP's profile mentioned continuing education in programming, which is why I expected that he or she will be moving to more advanced techniques soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is important to get a grip on the problem before developing.

The main questions are:

- Where will you get the information about the exp. (manual input in your program, or available on-line as open data)?
- Will you put your lvl in the app, or will you use the Runescape highscores API ([Runescape Highscores API](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Hiscores_APIs)) and just give your UserId?
- Will you get the data on the fly, or will you load them once (e.g. startup of your application). What will you do if your application runs for a long time?
- How will you calculate the result you want? Are there error margins?

Afterward, you should start thinking about your UI.

- Will this application be transported to different platforms?
- Will you use only a text interface or something more graphical?

An now is the time to make the choice for the development architecture (what part of the code will run where: server, client, web-based, etc...). Once this choice is made, you can make a choice of development language or languages.

Visual Studio Express seems a good choice, since it permits you to choose a number of development options: client/Server, client, web application, database application, choice of development language (C, C++, C#, F), ...

Now is the time to do what Steve V. advises you to do.

As already said above: your question is general, so I could not get into more detail.

Good luck !