# Reporting on test scenarios for a non-technical audience?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, reporting

I have (jUnit) unit tests.

My project manager would like a human-friendly list of test cases and scenarios (think: a spreadsheet or report for general distribution to a less technical audience).

What is an effective way to bridge this gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [StoryTeller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/). I haven't used it, but as I understand it it's a way to write acceptance tests in non-technical language, or at least a domain-specific language (DSL).

[This interview](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/storyteller) with Jeremy Miller, the creator, gives a pretty good description.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the "answer" but it's a lead in the right direction, so I'll take it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are for testing software components.

A less technical audience is (in my opinion) more interested in functionality than in implemention, in features than components.

That's the gap you need to bridge: the gap between a component and a feature.

The audience may be more interested in system test results than in unit test results; see also [Should one test internal implementation, or only test public behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856115)

People might be interested in lists of tests if the tests a) Test something interesting, and b) Have a name which reflects what it's testing. For example, there's [a list of my test case names here](http://www.modeltext.com/html/performance.aspx#test_cases) and if you're interested in that functionality I think you can tell from the names of tests approximately what's being tested (and conversely, what functionality has been broken if a regression test ever failed).

Comment: Also, ask your boss: what do they want to know when they read the report ... why are they reading the report, what are they hoping to get out of it (or why is he giving it to them)? Do they want to know what's broken? Do they want to know what's being worked on? Do they want to see "velocity"? Do they want to know how long everything will take to fix?

Comment: Good food for thought. Perhaps I need to think about the code tests vs. project-level "test scenarios" in more detail. Thanks for taking the time to respond.