# Objective-C properties - strong and weak declarations in categories

Tags: objective-c

How does the Objective-C runtime treat a property that is defined as `weak` in a class, but a private category on the class defines a property of the same name and type as `strong`?

Will code running in the context of the Category use the original (weak) modifier, or will it use the category defined modifier (strong)?

For example:

Name.m

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

NameTests.m

```
@interface Name (Test)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
```

Comment: Good question! I am surprised that this even compiles (although you can probably find out what happens there with a small test setup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a property declaration, `weak` only applies to the synthesized setter method, if any, and synthesized instance variable, if any.  If neither of those are synthesized then `weak` has no effect.

If the setter and instance variable are synthesized, the question then is: which property declaration is the compiler using to synthesize the setter and instance variable?

The compiler will never synthesize a property declared in a named category.  So in your example, `name` is a weak property.

Answer (score 0):

When adding properties with ambiguous names at runtime (which happens when you extend a class with a category), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used.
This is simply a naming clash that can be avoided by prefixing your category method/property. There are some details about prefixing in the "Avoid Category Method Name Clashes" section of Apple's ["Programming With Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) Guidelines.

When you build a simple test project you could probably observe, that the runtime randomly uses one of the two implementations. (When testing this, avoid constant strings for your name property, because they won't expose the behaviour)

By using a class extension instead of a named category, the compiler will generate an "Illegal redeclaration of property" error.

Comment: The naming clash is actually intentional.  It's a technique to enable unit testing of otherwise private properties and methods.  The category on the original class can selectively expose private properties and methods to a test class, without needing to break the encapsulation of those items within the "real" code.  Checkout "Privacy isn't Guaranteed" at https://engineering.aweber.com/improving-ios-unit-tests-with-ocmock   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290404/unit-testing-private-methods-from-a-category